# What does the image tell us the right side DL parts where we extract 3 spectrograms and then what operation they perform to get (128,216,3)?

Tags: audio, classification, signal-processing, librosa, spectrogram

I am not getting the DL part of the image as attached.
what does (128,216,3) the 3 shows? As 128 is number of bins n_mel=128 and 216 number of frames by keeping hop_length =512. what is 3 there? what operation they perform to get 3?

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQgKg.png)
```

if the 3 shows 3d array of 3 spectrogram is this correct then?
My code is
#########################################################################3
import librosa
import numpy as np

## Load the audio file

y, sr = librosa.load(r'G:\A NEW RESEARCH DATASET\1Fire\2_Fire.wav')  # Replace 'path_to_your_audio_file.wav' with your audio file path

## List of n_fft values

n_ffts = [2048, 1024, 512]

## List to hold spectrograms

spectrograms = []

## Generate spectrograms for each n_fft value

for n_fft in n_ffts:
mel_spec = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=512, n_mels=128)
spectrograms.append(mel_spec)

## Stack the spectrograms along the third dimension

tensor = np.stack(spectrograms, axis=-1)

print(tensor.shape)  # This should print (90, time_steps, 3), where time_steps depends on the length of your audio file